# Adding an existing Feature class to an existing Feature Dataset in c#(arcobjects)

Tags: arcobjects, feature-class, feature-dataset

I want to add an **existing feature class to an existing feature dataset**. Both the feature class and the dataset have the same coordinate system, I searched over the net but only assistance I found was to create a new feature class in a feature dataset (I tried that and it worked). According my understanding I tried using `IDatasetContainer` but it's not working. Here is the code:

```c#
IFeatureDataset featureDataset1 = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureDataset("featureDataset1");
IDataset datasetFcTenActors = fc_tenActors as IDataset;  // fc_tenActors is my feature class to add
IDatasetContainer container = featureDataset1 as IDatasetContainer;
container.AddDataset(datasetFcTenActors);
```

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe : thanks
but I am able to do the same using arcmaps by simply copying the feature class and pasting into the feature dataset.
Also there is already a line feature class present in the feature dataset which I created but not copy.

Comment: It doesn't change when I drag and drop but changes when I copy paste.
I want to code the drag and drop into feature dataset.

Comment: ok.. Got it. I was misunderstanding your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the code does not work?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe : I tried the above code and gave COM exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004022D" on the line -

container.AddDataset(datasetFcTenActors);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the IFeatureDataConverter2.ConvertFeatureClass Method does what you need:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/d/0025000002w5000000.htm

It takes a source Featureclass Name and an Output featuredataset Name as Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `IDatasetContainer` interface lets you move datasets between `FeatureDataset`s and `Workspaces`—both objects implement the interface. However, It should be used to move datasets between Feature Datasets within a single workspace, but not between workspaces. If you situation doesn't meet this precondition, follow Chris suggestion (`IFeatureDataConverter2`). Note that when moving feature classes into a feature dataset, **the spatial reference of the source feature class must match** the spatial reference of the target feature dataset.